# how to clean LED Anti-Glare Panel display?

Tags: laptop, monitors, displays, led

I want to clean my ASUS 15.6" (16:9) LED backlit FHD (1920x1080) 60Hz Anti-Glare Panel with 45% NTSC display.
can anyone tell me the right way to do this. thanks.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hardware Recs! Here at HW we are best poised to give you purchase recommendations about electronic items. This unfortunately means we do not give technical support (as Super User is better suited for those types of question) or answer questions not directly related to electronic hardware. Refer to [this meta post](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware) if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a commercially available screen cleaning kit like [this one from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01054S5FM).  You could also potentially use a soft microfiber cloth with water and a tiny amount of dish soap (put the slightly soapy water directly on the cloth and not the screen and make sure the cloth is only damp and not dripping wet).  Make sure you do NOT USE abrasive or astringent cleaners as they can permanently damage your screen.

Comment: Alcohol wipes work well and would be considered safe, in practice so are most glass cleaners - although theoretically they may interact with any special coating that may be on the screen. (I've never had an issue though).

Comment: Alcohol wipes are better then water because it evaporates and won't get into the screen. Arguably soapy water is more risky then glass cleaner.

Comment: glass cleaner is NOT typically vinegar (or acetic acid) - they typically contain 1 or more of Isporopyl Alccohol, Ethanol, Butyl Glycol, Monoethanolamine, Sodium Sulphate and/or citric (not ascetic) acid.

Comment: Fair point, comment deleted.  The ingredients of glass cleaner have apparently changed since I last read the label.  Whether those chemicals could harm an anti-glare coating is debatable.  It's safest to use a product specifically designed to clean screens without affecting coatings.